# GtkTreeIter Pointer Fails

Tags: gtk

For the following code from a GTK tutorial on setting up a tree:

```
 /* Create a model.  We are using the store model for now, though we
 * could use any other GtkTreeModel */

 store = gtk_tree_store_new (N_COLUMNS,
                                G_TYPE_STRING,
                                G_TYPE_STRING,
                                G_TYPE_STRING);


GtkTreeIter iter;

gtk_tree_store_append (store, &iter, NULL);

/* Acquire an iterator */

gtk_tree_store_set (store, &iter,
                    WORD, "antidisestablishmentarianism",
                    COUNT, "29",
                    LINES, "1,33,89",
                    -1);


gtk_tree_store_append (store, &iter, NULL);

gtk_tree_store_set (store, &iter,
                    WORD, "monkey",
                    COUNT, "2",
                    LINES, "1,55",
                    -1);
```

The code fails if instead of passing a reference to iter, I declare a pointer and pass it:

```
GtkTreeIter *iter;
gtk_tree_store_append (store, iter, NULL);
```

Any idea why? Would appreciate any insight thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GtkTreeIter *iter;
gtk_tree_store_append (store, iter, NULL);
```

What value does iter have right here? It's not defined. `GtkTreeIter` struct is not allocated anywhere. Passing such a pointer is UB.

You should either allocate it on stack (`GtkTreeIter iter`) or on heap (`GtkTreeIter * iter = g_new (GtkTreeIter, 1)`)